# Horizontal UITableView not displaying content after changing frame

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I have created a horizontal UITableView by rotating my tableView 90 degrees. And added to my view.

```
UITableView *myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
myTableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1.5707);
[self addSubview:self.myTableView];
```

It is displaying the contents properly and works fine (Similar to a UIScrollView).

I have to shift the tableView to the right and reduce its width to fit another view(say secondView) adjacent to the scroll view. So i change the frame of the tableView as :

```
self.myTableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.secondView.frame.size.width,
                                    self.myTableView.frame.origin.y,
                      self.myTableView.frame.size.width - self.secondView.frame.size.width,
                      self.myTableView.frame.size.height);
```

The frame of the tableView changes but its content's are not being displayed i.e I see blank cells. Can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: because the tabel cell is still to it's default size so the data is not shown.

Comment: It worked. There was some problem with the cell's size. Thanks.